# 'caught segfault' and 'memory not mapped' in R running clogit

Tags: r, segmentation-fault, survival-analysis

I'm trying to run a conditional logistic regression on a 9 by 484995115 matrix using following script in R

```
library(splines)
library(survival)
All <- read.table(pipe("cut -d';' -f1,2,4-9 /scratch/rvonscha/all.txt"), header=TRUE, 
sep=";", na.strings="NA", dec=",", strip.white=TRUE)
model <- clogit(Alliance ~ OVB + BVB + CVC + EarlyStage + AvgVCSize + NumberVC +   
strata(Strata), data=All)
summary(model)
```

But after 2h of calculation on a node with 256GB memory, the program stops with following error message:

```
*** caught segfault ***
address 0x7f687db38700, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
1: model.matrix.default(Terms2, m)
2: model.matrix(Terms2, m)
3: coxph(formula = Surv(rep(1, 484995115L), Alliance) ~ OVB + BVB +     CVC +      
EarlyStage + AvgVCSize + NumberVC + strata(Strata),     method = "exact")
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
5: eval(coxcall, sys.frame(sys.parent()))
6: clogit(Alliance ~ OVB + BVB + CVC + EarlyStage + AvgVCSize +     NumberVC + 
strata(Strata))
aborting ...
```

What can be the reason for this error? The memory capacity has never been exceeded during the calculation time. 
What could I change in the code to avoid this error?

I would really appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This is a bug. Test if you can reproduce it with `model.matrix.default` used directly and report it.

Comment: Also add the output from `sessionInfo()` to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce the bug with model.matrix.default because the dataset with 10GB was too big. Finally, I reduced the amount of data from 440 to 300 Mio lines and R finished the calculation.